Failure: Build failed with an exception to
The error:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.



* Where:

Build file 'C:\Users\Bala\Documents\flutter_project\magic_ball_app\android\app\build.gradle' line: 29



* What went wrong:

A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Could not get unknown property 'versionCode' for extension 'flutter' of type FlutterExtension.



* Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.

> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

> Run with --scan to get full insights.



* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org



BUILD FAILED in 900ms

Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                           1,634ms

Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

This is my build.gradle:
plugins {

    id "com.android.application"

    id "kotlin-android"

    // The Flutter Gradle Plugin must be applied after the Android and Kotlin Gradle plugins.

    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"

}



android {

    namespace = "com.example.magic_ball_app"

    compileSdk = flutter.compileSdkVersion

    ndkVersion = flutter.ndkVersion



    compileOptions {

        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

    }



    kotlinOptions {

        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

    }



    defaultConfig {

        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).

        applicationId = "com.example.magic_ball_app"

        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.

        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.

        minSdk = flutter.minSdkVersion

        targetSdk = flutter.targetSdkVersion

        versionCode = flutter.versionCode

        versionName = flutter.versionName

    }



    buildTypes {

        release {

            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.

            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.

            signingConfig = signingConfigs.debug

        }

    }

}



flutter {

    source = "../.."

}

